# Interpreting text entry and splitting it in a Manipulate text field?

Tags: manipulate, string-manipulation, text

I have the following program that plots the number of [trigram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigram) appearances across a corpus of textual information between 1964 and 1989 (apologies for the messy code):

```
Manipulate[
 viewerCount1 = {};
 SetDirectory["/users/ME/desktop/DB/Put/"];
 filenames = FileNames["*trigrams-put.txt"];
 Do[
  input = Get[file];
  Clear[trigramHash];
  (trigramHash[Sequence @@ #1] = #2) & @@@ input;
  count = trigramHash[word1, word2, word3]; trigramHash[___] = 0; 
  AppendTo[viewerCount1, count];
  , {file, filenames}];
 DateListPlot[viewerCount1, {1964}, Joined -> True, 
  PlotLabel -> "Number of Trigram Appearances"], {{word1, "i", 
   "Word1:"}}, {{word2, "love", "Word2:"}}, {{word3, "you", 
   "Word3:"}}]
```

Right now, it looks like so:

[image]

What this is doing is initially seeing how frequent the phrase "i love you" is across files like this:

```
{{{"i", "don", "t"}, 102}, {{"i", "m", "gonna"}, 67}, 
 {{"wa", "wa", "wa"}, 66}, {{"i", "can", "t"}, 66}, {{"i", "ll", "be"}, 66}, 
 {{"i", "love", "you"}, 62}, {{"you", "don", "t"}, 55}, 
 {{"la", "la", "la"}, 50}, {{"don", "t", "you"}, 49}, 
 {{"don", "t", "know"}, 48}, {{"ain", "t", "that"}, 47},
```

The problem is that in this version you have to type word1 as `"i"`, word2 as `"love"`, and word3 as `"you"`.

Would there be a way for *Mathematica* to detect `"i love you"` in the `Manipulate` box, and then return responses as if it was `"i" "love" "you"`? So it could just be a phrase box, and it would split them in to three parts. (I have separate programs right now for unigrams, bigrams, trigrams, and quadgrams)

Comment: Can't you use `StringSplit`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you can just use `StringSplit` at `Whitespace` characters.

Here is a toy example that might get you started.

```
Manipulate[
 PieChart[MapThread[Labeled[#2, #1] &, 
   Transpose[Tally@StringSplit[ngram, Whitespace]]]], {{ngram, 
   "One fish two fish red fish blue fish", "n-gram"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is great. I will play around with this!